# compress dll inside wpf executable created in net core

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll, bundle

I have a wpf program made on the net core 3.1, when it is compiled it creates 2 files which are the dll and the executable.

I'm looking for a way to hide my dll inside the executable.

I don't want to use the net core single file option, as it always extracts all the content to the temporary folder

I tried to use the net reactor bundle option the job is done, but the executable does not open, I just click it does nothing, nor does an error occur, it simply does not open.

Is there any other way for me to leave my dll generated inside the executable?

Comment: Seems the extraction to a temp folder is no longer needed in .net 5. Perhaps try changing the target framework could help. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: @MrBalanikas I will take a look at net 5

Comment: It doesn't matter net core 3.1 or net 5.0. The main important thing it is `Deployment mode` in publish settings. You can find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/media/single-file/visual-studio-publish-single-file-properties.png). It is the last screen from previous article.

Comment: @pablo kentch Check it and try to publish `wpf` application with this setting. I think it will help you

Comment: I am getting the following error when opening the publish executable **Unable to attach to the process. A debug component is not installed** if I compile the code normally without using publish the program runs perfectly